# The start of a Gaussian Function?

Tags: functions

The Gaussian Function is defined by:
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fve3R.png)

I was wondering if anyone could help me find the origin / base of the function (not sure what it's called). Basically, the x of where the function begins to increase in y.

Ps. I am unaware of the full terminology, and I would appreciate it if you could tell me the terms for finding the "base" or start of a function.

Thank you.

Comment: This function is increasing for each $x < c$ and decreasing otherwise.

Comment: But how would you obtain the x at which it begins to do so? I found that +- 3 std deviations hold 99.7% of the y values. But is there a way of obtaining the exact x at which it begins to increase?

Comment: Okay. Are you asking where the normal PDF is increasing, or where the CDF is incressing? (Spoiler: the CDF is increasing everywhere)

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, sorry. I am merely trying to find the x coordinate at which the function begins (or is away to begin) increasing in y.

Comment: It doesn't “begin increasing” anywhere. It's increasing in the whole interval $x \in (-\infty,b]$.